# Oracle ADF, Oracle Rich Client user interface, Fusion FX - connection between those terms?

Tags: java, oracle-adf

It is really not easy to find Infos about the following terms, which occur on the following website

**Terms**:

- Oracle ADF
- Oracle Rich Client user interface
- Fusion FX

**Website**: 
http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/ux/middleware/richclient/index.html

Whats the definition / connection between those terms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle ADF is an Application Development Framework. Oracle ADF is the umbrella name for layers of interconnected frameworks(ADFm, ADFc, ADFv, etc).

Oracle Rich Client is basically the ADFv layer. At the most basic level, ADFv is a collection of JSF components although Rich Client is certainly more than that.

Fusion FX is the name of the default look and feel(e.g. skin) of Rich Client. If I am not mistaken, there were other default skins in the past(blaf?).

Answer (score 0):

ADF uses 'Rich components' (like rich inputtext).
Fusion FX is a default style/skin type if I'm not mistaking.